# Site Scraping for JavaScript rendered site

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, jsoup

I'm trying to get the part numbers of which items go in their respective categories from http://www.dynacorn.com/ListItems.aspx but, for me at least, the catch is that the pages are paginated and therefore I cannot figure out how to move on to the next page. I've been reading about JSoup but am unsure of how to implement this. Can someone show me an example of how I could go from page to page when scraping?

Thanks!

Comment: look for the next link, and load it, scrape, rinse, repeat

Comment: lol...thank you...that part had not escaped me.

Comment: Jsoup cannot parse javascript generated content. You need a headless browser for that. Check HtmlUnit or Selenium webdriver. There are a lot of good answers here in SO about this particular topic.